# Language detection for very short text

Tags: nlp, nltk, language-detection

I'm creating an application for detecting the language of short texts, with an average of < 100 characters and contains slang (e.g tweets, user queries, sms).

All the libraries I tested work well for normal web pages but not for very short text. The library that's giving the best results so far is Chrome's Language Detection (CLD) library which I had to build as a shared library.

CLD fails when the text is made of very short words. After looking at the source code of CLD, I see that it uses 4-grams so that could be the reason.

The approach I'm thinking of right now to improve the accuracy is:

- Remove brand names, numbers, urls and words like "software", "download", "internet"
- Use a dictionary When the text contains a number of short words above a threashold or when it contains too few words.
- The dictionary is created from wikipedia news articles + hunspell dictionaries.

What dataset is most suitable for this task? And how can I improve this approach?

So far I'm using EUROPARL and Wikipedia articles. I'm using NLTK for most of the work.

Comment: Have you managed to build the CLD as a shared library?  Would you care to share this?

Comment: @Stuart yes I have. You need to pass this as an argument when building:
`./build/gyp_chromium -f make -D library=shared_library`
then only take the specific library you want `make cld`.
Full instructions here http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxFasterBuilds

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Language detection for very short texts is the topic of current research, so no conclusive answer can be given. An algorithm for Twitter data can be found in [Carter, Tsagkias and Weerkamp 2011](http://scarter.org/papers/websci2011-twitteruse.pdf). See also the references there.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is a topic of research and there is some progress that has been made.

For example, the author of "language-detection" at http://code.google.com/p/language-detection/ has created new profiles for short messages. Currently, it supports 17 languages.

I have compared it with Bing Language Detector on a collection of about 500 tweets which are mostly in English and Spanish. The accuracy is as follows:

```
   Bing = 71.97%
   Language-Detection Tool with new profiles = 89.75%
```

For more information, you can check his blog out: 
http://shuyo.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/language-detection-supported-17-language-profiles-for-short-messages/

Comment: Unfortunately, the download link it down. The only outcome  is to build the jar.

Answer (score -2):

Also omit scientific names or names of medicines etc. Your approach seems quite fine to me. I think wikipedia is the best option for creating a dictionary as it contains standard language. If you are not running out of time, you can also use newspapers.