# Extract only English sentences

Tags: algorithm, nlp

I need to extract posts and tweets from Facebok and Twitter into our database for analysis. My problem is the system can process on the English sentences (phrases) only. So how can I remove non-English posts, tweets from my database.

If you do know any algorithm in NLP can do this, please tell me.

Thanks and regards

Comment: This sounds like a Language Identification problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_identification

Comment: possible duplicate of [Language detection for very short text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579974/language-detection-for-very-short-text) (my answer there covers Twitter specifically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this project, the source code is very clear. I have tested and it runs pretty well.
http://code.google.com/p/guess-language/

Answer (score 4):

Avoiding automatic language identification where possible is usually preferable - for instance, https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search shows that returned tweets contain a field `iso_language_code` which might be helpful.

If that's not good enough, you'll have to either

- look for existing language identification libraries in whatever language you're using; or
- get your hands on a sufficient amount of English text (dumps of English Wikipedia, say, or any of the Google n-gram models) and implement something like http://www.cavar.me/damir/LID/.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I know this API from Twitter, the problem is my posts are not only coming from Twitter but can be from Facebook, search engine,...

Answer (score 3):

Get an English dictionary and see if the majority of the words in your text are in it. Since you are looking at online text, be sure to include common slang and abbreviations.

This can run very quickly if you store the dictionary in a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure.

I think fancy NLP is a bit overkill for this task. You don't need to identify the language if it's not English so all you have to do is test your text with some simple characteristics of the English language.

Comment: This is unlikely to work well due to the prevalence of English words in other languages. Looking for English *stop words* might be a smarter idea.

Comment: While I'm sure there are many English words that are valid in other languages, I have a hard time believing that the most of the words in a text would be. I'm sure you find a threshold that works for 99.99% of cases.

Comment: I'm sure it's a lot harder than you think, and I base my opinion on my thesis research for which I read quite the literature on language guessing, and on my colleagues' research into [language guessing for Twitter](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~tsagias/?p=241). What you suggest is a method that was tried in the early 1990s for much larger and cleaner documents than tweets, and didn't work well even then.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried using standard libraries for language detection on tweets. You will get a lot of false negatives because there are a lot of non-standard characters in names, smilies etc. This problem is more severe in smaller posts where the signal-to-noise ratio is lower.

The main problem is not the algorithm but the outdated data-sources. I would suggest crawling/streaming a new one from Twitter. The language flag in Twitter is based on geographical information, so that will not work in all cases. (A chinese person can still make chinese posts in USA). I would suggest using a white-list of a lot of English speaking persons and collect their posts.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little tweet language classifier (either english or not) that was 95+% accurate if I'm remembering right. I think it was just naive bayes + 1000 training instances. Combine that with location information and you can do even better.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried SVD (Single Value Decomposition) for LSI (Latent Semantic Indexing) & LSA (Latent Semantic Analysis) ? see: http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/svd/read-me.html